# How to load resource file in a dependency jar contained in the Spring Boot jar file?

Tags: spring-boot

When packaging the Spring Boot application as a single jar, all the dependency jars are also contained in that jar file. It forms a hierarchical structure of jars. How can I access to the resource file(such as a xml) that built in one of the dependency jar without unpackaging them?

Answer (score -1):

If dependency jar is in your classpath, you can read XML files like:

```
URL loadedResource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(“your.xml”);
InputStream inputStream = loadedResource.openStream();
```

OR

```
Resource resource=new CLassPathResource(“your.xml”);
resource.getInputStream();
```

Follow this [stackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) thread

If it is properties file you want to read, you can use ***@PropertySource*** annotation:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:your.properties")
```